# regex find and replace every nth occurrence in notepad++

Tags: javascript, regex, notepad++

I've a large text file (15000 lines). every line ends with /txt
I want to change every 5th lines to end with txt5.
I've searched Internet but not found a solution to work for me.

```
somethingDifferent/txt
somethingDifferent/txt
somethingDifferent/txt
somethingDifferent/txt
somethingDifferent/txt
somethingDifferent/txt
somethingDifferent/txt
somethingDifferent/txt
somethingDifferent/txt
somethingDifferent/txt
```

to:

```
somethingDifferent/txt
somethingDifferent/txt
somethingDifferent/txt
somethingDifferent/txt
somethingDifferent/txt5
somethingDifferent/txt
somethingDifferent/txt
somethingDifferent/txt
somethingDifferent/txt
somethingDifferent/txt5
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: That's not quite a duplicate since it doesn't deal with newlines in the source file. It is a rather trivial problem, admittedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested with EditPadPro, but this should work in Notepad++ as well:

Search for

```
((?:^.*/txt\r\n){4}^.*/txt$)
```

and replace with

```
\15
```

**Explanation:**

```
(           # Start capturing group no. 1, referenced by \1 in the replacement expression
 (?:        # Start a non-capturing group that matches...
  ^.*/txt   # a complete line ending in /txt
  \r\n      # and a (Windows-style) carriage return
 ){4}       # four times in a row.
 ^.*/txt$   # Then match a fifth line just like that, but without the CR
)           # End of capturing group
```

Comment: Great answer, could you please also explain what `\1` in replace with means?